# Reverse engineering CRC16 algorithm from CRC16 and data set

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering, crc

I am using a poorly documented system where a CRC16 is needed in a structure that I need to modify.
Modification will not take effect unless I provide the correct checksum.

Technical support has indicated that they were using the standard CRC16, but using the CRC16 CCITT would not give me the result.

I have a small snippet of data and the checksum that it is supposed to have.

Can someone help me find the proper CRC16 parameters (polynomial, initial value) that will match my data set?

Another thing. On the platform in question, addresses are organized with 16 bit words for each address, so I tried both the original byte order and the reversed byte order.

```
Data Set #  1
crc         0xb19f
data @b306: 7a b1 74 44 9f 84 74 5b  
length      8 bytes

Data Set # 2
crc        0x447b
data @0036 00 43 e2 05 5b 03 00 02 00 16 00 00 00 00 00 00
           00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           12 c0 00 00 00 07 f7 ff 3f e5 ff ff 3f ff 75 30
           3a 98 00 01 00 9d 00 0f 00 09 00 0a 00 00 00 00
           00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 80 0f
           47 44 09 6d 0a 35 09 c4 f0 00 00 40 10 00 00 01
           07 d0 27 10 00 00 ff 38 00 5a ff 06 0a fd 00 05
length     128 bytes
```

Knowing what I know now, I thing I choose poorly when I selected the organization that does not provide much technical support, I know that now.

[EDIT:]
Processor is ~ 8051 but not sure about endianness. My test code tests for both types of endianness as a matter of course.

[EDIT:]
I found this other question helpful:
[CRC16 and data communications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453859/crc16-and-data-communications)

Comment: I would try to loop all possible initialization values for the CRC16 for the datasets. Calculating 65536 times the same CRC should not take too long on a modern PC

Comment: Firstly, CRC16 is not the same as CRC16 CCITT - so why would you expect it to work?  Secondly, [this page](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/crc16-ccitt.html) says broken implementations are common, so you might want to find one or two that generate different results from whatever correct implementation you find, and see if any of them match what your product's using.  Thirdly, why the [c++], [c] and [embedded] tags? -1 for dishonestly attracting an audience!

Comment: @Tony D, sorry about the C++ and C tag, I removed them. As for embedded, this is honest, an embedded platform, which I can not name for fear of shaming them for providing such poor support.

Comment: @Bamaco: my -1 gone then (though embedded can be true while being ostensibly irrelevant to the question as posed), but if they've used this CRC approach widely throughout their software, naming them might be the most practical way to get actual experience and help....

Comment: @Tony D, firstly about the CRC16 CCITT, thats the most "standard" that I know about. If there is a better standard, I could not find it by reading the wikipedia page on the subject.

Comment: @Bamaco: from the document I link above: *"Why focus on the 16-bit CRC-CCITT (polynomial 0x1021) and not CRC16 (polynomial 0x8005), which appears to have wider use?"* - that's enough to tell me they're different beasts with different outputs.

Comment: @Tony D, the CRC approach is not widely used throughout their software. It is just used in some header found in EEPROM. The EEPROM image, generated from compiler output, is validated from a primary processor to which I have no access, with ROM code. The only reference to CRC in this system is in these headers.

Comment: @Bamaco Yup - I feel for you - ugly situation.  May end up having to "social engineer" the extact CRC code/algo out of them somehow....  Good luck!

Comment: What's the processor?  That should at least tell you the endianess.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I have edited my original question to reflect the fact that the processor is ~ 8051

Comment: Try entering you data into an online CRC Calculator such as [this one](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html).  If you can cut and paste your appropriately formatted data into the field then it will automatically calculate a variety of CRC algorithms.

Comment: @kkrambo, I tried the result before, accounting for both types of endianness and I got no good results, sorry.

Comment: You could try using http://reveng.sourceforge.net/  it appears to do exactly what you are asking.  I have not tried it on your data as it requires compilation of the source (and I am on a Chromebook), but I had a similar problem a while back and may give it a go.

Comment: Thanks @Clifford, I find reveng a bit challenging, but I am adding a link for other who may stumble into this question, for reference.[CRC16 and data communications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453859/crc16-and-data-communications/16454079#16454079)

Comment: @Bamaco : reveng may be challenging, but then so is your problem.  Perhaps worth persevering.  You could even e-mail the author for advice.

Comment: @Clifford, I managed to use reveng, but it did not yield any answers. It could not find the CRC. I have since gotten a reply with some code and I have posted an answer with the link to it.

Comment: @Bamaco : Cool; perhaps you might post the reveng command line you used?

Comment: @Clifford, I posted it before, but I was only able to issue the command with the strings argument, I could not get it to accept to read strings from separate files. It was so ugly and unhelpful that I got -1 for posting such an awful contraption. See linked question for example of arguments for reveng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code linked in your own answer seems to have a lot of unrelated code in it, but the 16 bit CRC function mentions two polymonials:

```
x^16+x^5+x^2+1.
x^16+x^12+x^5+1
```

but the comment that mentions these suggests that the author has not realised that one is simply the reverse version of the the other which may be why there is confusion over the documentation.  Either way it is the CRC-16-CCITT polynomial (as used in X.25, V.41, HDLC, XMODEM, Bluetooth, SD, many others; known as CRC-CCITT).  That is not to say that it is implemented correctly of course or that the comment even is correct.

It looks like a ragged collection of code from multiple sources. You have to wonder about a vendor relying on code and algorithms of unknown provenance and obvious confusion!

Incidentally, the 32 bit CRC in the same code uses the CRC-32 polynomial (as used in ISO 3309, ANSI X3.66, FIPS PUB 71, FED-STD-1003, ITU-T V.42, Ethernet, SATA, MPEG-2, Gzip, PKZIP, POSIX cksum, PNG, ZMODEM).

---

### Later edit:

I have found it, using this site: http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html and a great deal of trial and error.  Unfortunately the site takes data in ASCII, so I converted the 8 byte sample to text using http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm (which yields "`z±tDt[`" - *note that the string contains some non-printing characters, but copy&pasting them from the site appears to include them as it reports 8 bytes whereas the string here is 6 - do not copy and paste from this post*).

Any how the configuration that yields the result given in your data sample is as follows:

[image: Screenshot of www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html]
Set-up as follows:

- click CRC-CCITT,
- with the "initial value" set to FFFF, click the "Convert!" (to "non-direct" which transforms the value of 84CF),
- set "final XOR" to FFFF,
- check "reverse data bytes",
- enter data in ASCII,
- click "Compute!" button.

Comment: Your screen shot shows initial value with 0x84CF but the text below says 0xFFFF.

Comment: @Bamaco : Follow the steps.  I arrived at 84CF by selecting CRC-CCITT which sets the field to FFFF which when converted becomes 84CF.  The point being to indicate how the value was arrived at - not magic!  It is perhaps not the most intuitive interface, but it provides more options than any other on-line CRC tool I have found.  To see what all the controls actually do, you could look at the Java script, and the site has a link to C code that supports all the same options.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I got the reply from the embedded chip manufacturer.

[The code links here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.c)

Does not look like a standard CRC16 to me and I am not surprised that [reveng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) was unable to determine the CRC algorithm in use.

Comment: Thanks @Ross, I have edited the unhelpful answer and replaced it by the actual answer.